# problem with jquery .hide()

Tags: jquery

Hey guys I've got a simple problem with jQuery but to be honest it don't get it what I'm doing wrong.

The JQuery code just looks like that

```
$(".submit_twitter,.submit_url").hide();
$(".submit_url").show();
```

Now I expect to see only the submit button with class="submit_url", but instead both submit buttons are shown? ;(

Using just

```
  $(".submit_twitter").hide();
```

instead didn't work either.

EDIT:

I'm using it like that right now:

```
$(".submit_twitter,.submit_url").hide();
$(".submit_url").show();
$(".url2,.notsignedin").hide();
$(".counter").hide();
```

it works as far as it doesnt show classes "url2", "notsignedin" and "counter" but submit classes are shown. functions are called from an extern .js file which starts with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { .......
```

As you see it is pretty strange why some parts do work and others dont.

EDIT 2 - fixed:
ah found the problem myself, had another function which was using keyup event, there the input length was used to show/hide the submit_twitter button like if (len > 140) hide button, else show button, this function was responsible for showing the button all the time as the len was ofcourse less then 140 characters.

Comment: I can see it working! http://jsfiddle.net/pENEh/6/

Comment: Is there an error message in the console?  Does your selector match?  Does your CSS have a display setting set to important?

Answer (score 0):

- make sure you used the same class name on element and jquery selector (submit_twitter)
- make sure your script executes after element is added to DOM

Comment: I've updated my first post, there you can see that the script works partial, some classes which should be hidden are hidden, others not.

Comment: ah found the problem myself, had another function which was using keyup event, there the input length was used to show/hide the submit_twitter button like if (len > 140) hide button, else show button, this function was responsible for showing the button all the time as the len was ofcourse less then 140 characters.